# django-orm - Making sure clean() is called while updating a queryset through admin_actions

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How can make I sure that the `clean()` method is getting called while executing `queryset.update('somefield'=True)`. I also need to make sure that I am catching any `ValidationError` thrown by `clean()` method.

I have very little experience with django ORM. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models' `clean` method isn't called when using the queryset's `update` function. Have a look at the [update documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update).

You're going to have to write your own admin_action to ensure that the method is called. There's examples in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).

I think you want something like -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import YourModel

def update_and_clean(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
         obj(some_field=True)
         obj.clean()
         obj.save()

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [update_and_clean]

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks @aidan for helping me out. Your added example definitely makes the thing a lot clear. so i guess, i just need to add a try/except block for exceptions. :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot you mentioned catching exceptions. Yes, you would put your try / except in the update_and_clean method.

Comment: cool! I was just hoping/trying for a solution so that i don't have to iterate through all the objects and save them individually. Any thoughts on that line?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That's the point of the update function, it runs a SQL UPDATE. short of writing some custom SQL to do the job, you're really stuck with iterating django objects I think.